# Adding Excel data to attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, excel

How do I add or append excel data to an existing attribute table?

The excel column headings will match the attribute table headings (in name at least). Simply want to expand the attribute table without having to manually type all the data in.

Comment: Sounds like you should look into the Append or Merge tools.

Comment: Where are the geometries to go with your new Excel rows going to come from?

Answer (score 1):

Add both the excel and feature class (incl. attribute table) to the map. Then join them together and export as a new feature class. Example below for ArcMap. (To join right click on layer in tree - Joins and Relates)

[image]
After join export:
[image]

Comment: I think the asker is wanting a longer table with the same fields rather than a wider table with more fields.

Comment: Is it even possible to have one to many relationship (example one polygon - multiple rows in attribute table) or is he asking a non GIS question

Answer (score 0):

If you right click on the Feature class in ArcCatalog you can select Load which will load all (or filtered) values into the feature class you have. The problem you have here is that your points will have no geometry.

What you could do is join your shapes to the excel table, as suggested by @Bjorn, then export this the shape with your extra columns as a shapefile or Feature Class and load in into the original Feature Class. Take care to match up the column names correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The Append tool allows you to combine two feature classes with the same attributes in the same order. If one is a .csv file, you must first display the x-y data in ArcMap and export it as a shapefile or feature class.